# why is it showing error as 'TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()' even when i'm using 'n' as a list

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, compiler-errors, return-value

It's a code to return possible permutations of the list 'n'. But, even when i print the value using 'n' as a list, i still get 'Type error'

```
import copy

def permutation(n):
    if len(n) == 1:
        return [[n[0]]]
    else:
         a = copy.deepcopy(n)
         k = a.pop()
         a1 = n[len(n)-1]
         c = permutation(k)
         h = copy.deepcopy(c)
         i = 0
         while i < len(c):
             j = 0
             while j < len(c[i]):
                 x = c[i].insert(j,a1)
                 h.append(x)
                 j = j+1
             i = i + 1
    return(h)


print(permutation([1,2,4]))
```

Comment: So I see `k = a.pop()` and then `c = permutation(k)`. meaning that `k` is an item from the list `a` (which is a copy of `n`), meaning that `k` is an `int`, and you're passing that `int` as an argument to `permutation()`. My question is, why do you expect that to _not_ fail? Did you maybe mean to pass `[k]` and not just plain `k`? Did you not look up the documentation of `list.pop()`, and then just assumed that it returned a `list` with a single item in it?

Comment: @RandomDavis oh, I thought a.pop() would return as a list by removing the last element of a

Comment: Just look up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and you'll see that that's incorrect. The operation returns the removed element (which is by default the last item in the list when you pass in no arguments), and removes it from the original list. It's never a good idea to assume anything about how something works. And always start with the documentation rather than posting online first when you run into a problem like this - it would've saved you and us plenty of time.

Comment: Creating the required [mcve] would have shown you your faulty assumption, I believe. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The method pop() returns an int, not a list.

the variable 'k' which contains the return of the pop() method, was passed to the function as integer.

Comment: Oh, i see. Then how do i remove the last element of a list , is there any inbuilt function for that?

Comment: @Abhinav You may run the pop() method, without saving it's return value to any variable.